# Excel - allow copy/paste but no data entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet which is protected and a few contiguous cells which are editable. Is there a way I can allow a user to copy paste data into these cells, but the user should not be able to type in values directly into these cells? I am willing to accept a solution using VBA too.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anindya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock up all the cells so they can neither type nor copy into those cells.

You can ask the user to copy the cells they want.

Put a button on the Excel sheet that says "Paste details". When the click the buttton, use VBA code to paste the details at the specific cell range that you want.